# How does backwards induction work to prove a property for all naturals?

Tags: induction

I was reading a blogpost here: http://mzargar.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/cauchys-method-of-induction/ ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120309055020/https://mzargar.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/cauchys-method-of-induction/))

One thing that threw me off was that after the first four large displayed equations, there is the statement "it is sufficient to prove that if the theorem holds for $n=m+1$, then it holds for $n=m$."

How is this type of induction valid? I browsed around for things like backward induction, reverse induction, and Cauchy induction, but couldn't find a justification for how this is valid.

With the usual forward induction of verifying a base case and proving $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$, it's easy to intuitively understand how induction will show a property holds for all natural numbers (or at least starting at the base case). But with this reverse induction, it seems to me that if you prove $P(m+1)\implies P(m)$, then if you were able to verify a specific case like $P(15)$, then you would only know it's true for numbers up to $15$. How does it actually prove the property for all naturals?

Comment: This induction principle is applied to finite sets, not the infinite set of natural numbers.

Comment: I never thought it was applied to infinite sets, but isn't induction used to prove certain properties hold for all naturals? As in $2^n>n$ for all $n$? I'm just asking how you could draw the same conclusion from a different induction scheme.

Comment: You left out the first part of the sentence!  "***Now that we have the case when n is a power of 2 settled,*** _it is sufficient to prove...._"  The short answer is that you ***also*** prove that for any n, you can find N >= n for which it is true, usually by proving it true for some infinite set.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the OP rightly points out, $P(m+1) \Rightarrow P(m)$ alone does not imply that the property holds for all natural numbers. The proposed method needs two conditions:

- The property holds for infinitely many natural numbers; i.e., it holds for an infinite subsequence $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k < \cdots$. This is like the “base step” of the proof.
- $P(m+1)$ implies $P(m)$. This is the “induction step”.

A textbook example of this method is Cauchy’s proof of the AM-GM inequality. Martin’s answer links to a proof of “midpoint convexity implies convexity” using a similar idea.

**Proof of correctness.** The intuition behind this is that the base step identifies infinitely many numbers for which the property holds. But these numbers might contain gaps; we then work to fill these gaps in the induction step.

Let us make that a formal proof. Assume that the property $P$ fails to hold for at least one value of $n$, say $N$. Then rewriting the second hypothesis contrapositively as $\lnot P(m) \Rightarrow \lnot P(m+1)$ and applying standard mathematical induction to the hypothesis $\lnot P$, we conclude that $\lnot P(n)$ holds for all $n \geqslant N$; in other words, the property $P$ fails to hold eventually. But this contradicts the first assumption.  $\quad\diamond$

I end with a methodological remark. Notice that what I dubbed the base step in fact requires us to prove the proposition $Q(k) := P(n_k)$ for *infinitely many* $k$. This is reminiscent of standard induction, and unsurprisingly we often resort to it in this step. For instance, in the AM-GM proof, it is easy to prove that the AM-GM inequality holds for $2K$ numbers assuming it always holds for $K$ numbers; setting $K = 2^k$ gives a standard induction proof that $Q(k) := P(2^k)$ is true for all $k$.

Answer (score 19):

Cauchy induction consists of the following parts.

We want to show that $P(n)$ holds for any $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. To do this we show:

1. $P(1)$ is true;
2. $P(n)$ implies $P(2n)$;
3. $P(m+1)$ implies $P(m)$.

If *all* of the above conditions are true, then $P(n)$ holds for all integers.

---

*Intuition behind this:* By steps of the type $n\to 2n$ and $m+1\to m$ we can get from $1$ to any integer. E.g. if we want to get to the number $5$ we can do it like this:
$1\to2\to4\to8\to7\to6\to5$.
A different possibility:
$1\to2\to4\to3\to6\to5$.

---

*Formal proof:* Suppose that the above conditions are true. We will show by strong induction that $P(n)$ is true for each $n$.

$1^\circ$ For $n=1$ we have validity of $P(1)$.

$2^\circ$ Suppose that $n\ge 2$ and $P(k)$ is true for each $k$ such that $1\le k<n$.

If $n$ is even, we can use 2: Since $k=n/2<n$, we know that $P(k)$ is true, and thus $P(2k)=P(n)$ is true.

If $n$ is odd, we can use 3: Since $k=(n+1)/2<n$, we know that $P(k)$ is true. This implies that $P(2k)=P(n+1)$ is true. Now using 3 we get that $P(n)$ is true as well.

---

Useful links:

- Cauchy induction at [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Induction)
- Proof of AM-GM using this type of induction at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_Cauchy_using_forward%E2%80%93backward_induction) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means&oldid=1000918252#Proof_by_Cauchy_using_forward%E2%80%93backward_induction)).  They call this technique forward-backward-induction.
- One section of Pete L. Clark's [notes on induction](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3200induction.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20200109023617/https://math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3200induction.pdf)) is devoted to this type of induction. He calls it upward-downward induction.

AM-GM inequality is indeed the most frequent application used to illustrate the Cauchy induction.
You can find some proofs using Cauchy induction and some useful links e.g. in these answers:

- [AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/75672/)
- [AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27334/)
- [midpoint convexity and rational convexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83398/)

Comment: This is a nice way to look at this idea: if we write $P(a) \Rightarrow P(b)$ as a directed edge from $a$ to $b$, then as long as there is a finite-length path from $1$ to $n$, we can conclude that $P(n)$ is true (assuming, of course, that we already proved $P(1)$).

Comment: Well I tried to include something about intuition, too. Anyway, now that I've had a better look at your answer, I think I should have written about more general version. (I.e. $n_k$ instead of $2^k$, as in your answer.)

Comment: Why when n is odd we use 2 and k=n/2?

Comment: @AbdelrhmanFawzy I switched even and odd by mistake, it is corrected now. (If $n$ is odd, then $n/2$ is an integer. If $n$ is even, then $(n+1)/2$ is an integer.)

Comment: This was great. Cheers~~

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ This can be viewed as a sort of *interval* (or *segment*) induction.

**Lemma** $\rm\ S\subset \mathbb N\:$ satisfies $\rm\:n+1\in S\:\!\Rightarrow n \in S\:$ iff $\rm\:S\:$ is an initial segment of $\:\mathbb N$

**Proof** $ $ (hint) $ $ If $\rm\:S\ne \mathbb N\:$ then $\rm\:S = [0,m)\:$ for the least $\rm\:m\not\in S,\:$ since by induction, nonmembership ascends from $\rm\:m\:$ by $\rm\:n\not\in S\:\Rightarrow\:n+1\not\in S.\:$

**Corollary** $ $ If, additionally, $\rm\:S\:$ is unbounded then $\rm\:S = \mathbb N$

In your case $\rm\: S\ne \{\ \}\:$ is unbounded via the hypothesis $\rm\:n\in S\:\Rightarrow\:2\:\!n\in S.$

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused with the method of infinite descent which is used to prove that something is FALSE :
If $P(0)$ is false and if $P(n)$ implies that there exists a $m < n$ such that $P(m)$, then $P(n)$ is false for all $n$.
This correspond to prove the anteposition of the standard recurrence principle. (The anteposition of an implication $A\Rightarrow B$ is $\text{not} B \Rightarrow \text{not} A$.)

Comment: But that's not the situation in the blogpost. The claim is that $P(m+1)\implies P(m)$ is sufficient to show an inequality holds for all $n$. There is no question of proving something false.

Answer (score 0):

In the answers you will find the general theory behind the idea. But to understand how it works a good idea is to examine the following proof of a 'weak variant' of the this induction theory.

Lemma 1: Let $S$ be a subset of the natural numbers $\Bbb N$ satisfying, for every $n \ge 0$

$\tag 1 n \in S \text{ implies } n + 1 \in S$
$\tag 2 n+ 1 \in S \text{ implies } n  \in S$

Then $S = \Bbb N$ or $S = \emptyset$.
Proof
If the set isn't empty, then there exist a $\hat k \in S$. Using $\text{(1)}$ and applying weak induction, we see that if $k \ge \hat k$, then $k \in S$. Next, use Bill Dubuque's 'initial segment' lemma to show that $k \le \hat k$ implies $k \in S$. $\quad \blacksquare$