# Understanding Less Frequent Form of Induction? (Putnam and Beyond)

Tags: induction, contest-math

I won't paste the question here since my problem is not a technical one but a conceptual one.

Book is here: (Page 22 of the pdf)

I do not understand why it is necessarily to induct $2^{k}$ to show $2^{k+1}$ when the proof follows up with inducting backwards from (n+1) to (n). 
I recall a similar induction problem where backwards induction itself already suffice.

*Why it is necessarily to show the former $2^{k}$? Doesn't showing (n+1) to (n) already include in-itself the powers of $2$?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do insert more details in your question.

In any case, forward-backward induction is a very common concept, so here's my answer:

It is not sufficient to be able go from $n+1$ to $n$ because you don't have a large value of $n$ to start.

The forward part of going from $2^k$ to $2^{k+1}$ ensures that you have arbitrarily large values of $n$ from which you can go downwards.

Comment: In this case (the arithmetic mean–geometric mean inequality) doubling is easy to handle, and going down single steps is not particularly complicated using a specific term, but going up single steps is harder.

Comment: Just to make it a little more clear, what you do in this proof is that since you cannot do a forward induction for all natural numbers (easily?) you prove it for all natural powers of 2, and then by backward induction fill in the gap.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 2):

As I [explained in an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145572/242) to a similar question, this type of induction is most conceptually viewed as a sort of *interval* (or *segment*) induction. Intuitively, the essence of the matter is *extremely* simple: $\:\mathbb N\:$ is the only unbounded initial segment of $\:\mathbb N.\:$ Here are the details:

**Lemma** $\rm\ \ S\subset \mathbb N\:$ satisfies $\rm\:n\!+\!1\in S\:\!\Rightarrow n \in S\ \:$ iff $\rm\:\ S\:$ is an initial segment of $\:\mathbb N$

**Proof** $ $ (sketch) $\ $ If $\rm\:S\ne \mathbb N\:$ then $\rm\:S = [0,m)\:$ for the least $\rm\:m\not\in S,\:$ since by induction, nonmembership ascends from $\rm\:m\:$ to all $\rm\:n\ge m\:$ by $\rm\:n\not\in S\:\Rightarrow\:n\!+\!1\not\in S.\ \ $  **QED**

**Corollary** $ $ If, additionally, $\rm\:S\:$ is unbounded then $\rm\:S = \mathbb N.\ \ $ **QED**

In your case let $\rm\: S\ne \{\ \}\:$ be the set of naturals where the proposition is true. We know by hypothesis that $\rm\:S\:$ satisfies the Lemma so $\rm\:S\:$ is an initial segment of $\mathbb N.\:$ Furthermore, by hypothesis $\rm\:n\in S\:\Rightarrow\:2\:\!n\in S,\: $ hence $\rm\:S\:$ is unbounded. Therefore $\rm\:S = \mathbb N\:$ by the Corollary.

Comment: Thanks for the background!

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/166856/242) is a sample application proving $\rm\,gcd(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\,gcd(a^n,b^n)=1.$