# Squares of two coprime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers, coprime

If there are two coprime numbers a and b, then are a^2 and 
b^2 also coprime ?

Comment: Yes, they are. Any common prime factor of $a^2$ and $b^2$ would also divide $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Alternatively, here is the proof of a more general statement: [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a^n,b^n)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166839/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdan-bn-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the squares are also coprime.

Note that the prime factors of $a^2$ are the same as prime factors of $a$but the power of each prime in $a^2$ is twice the power of the same prime in $a$.

If $a$ and $b$ do not share a prime then $a^2$ and $b^2$ do not share any prime as well

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can see that two ways:

1. $a$  and $b$ coprime means they share no prime factor. As the prime factors of $n^2$ are exactly  the prime factors of $n$, but squared, we see $a^2$ and $b^2$ share no prime factors either.
2. Via *Bézout's identity*, we show that, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, $a^2$ and $b$ are too (and hence $a^2$ and $b^2$ are).

Indeed, coprimality of $a$ and $b$ means there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that $ua+vb=1$. Squaring this relation, we obtain
$$1=u^2a^2+2uvab+v^2b^2=u^2a^2+(2uva+v^2b)b.$$

Comment: Yes, it's a fine way – maybe less natural, and harder to generalise to proving $a^i$ and $b^j$ are coprime for any  $i,j$.