# Proving that if $a, b$ are coprime, then if $p^k \, | \, ab$, then $p^k \,|\, a$ or $p^k \,|\, b$ without Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to prove the following problem ($p$ is a prime number, and $k \in \mathbb{P}$)

If $a, b$ are coprime, then if $p^k \, | \, ab$, then $p^k \,|\, a$ or $p^k \,|\, b$ without Fundamental Arithmetic Theorem.

I can derive that $p \, | \, ab$, $a \, | \, ab$, and $b \, | \, ab$. But I am lost as to where to go from there. If anybody could hint me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, can you show that, if $p|cd$  and $c,d$  are coprime, then $p$  divides one of them but not the other?

Comment: Seems an argument by induction will help

Comment: If $c | (ab)$ and $(c, a) = 1,$ then $c | b.$

Answer (score 1):

As $p^k|ab$, assume $p^\alpha|a$ and $p^\beta|b$, where $\alpha+\beta=k$. Unless either $\alpha=0$ or $\beta=0$, then $a$ and $b$ aren't coprime as stipulated.

Comment: $\color{#c00}{{-}{\bf 1}}\,$ Not even a correct (complete) proof, let alone one that avoids FTA. You need to justify these claims, and the most common way uses FTA (or equivalents) - which OP seeks to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $p \mid ab$ and that $p \not\mid a$. Then there are $x,y$ such that
$$p^kx+ay=1$$ this is the Euclidean algorithm.

Multiply this equation by $b$,
$$p^kxb+aby=b$$ then $p^k$ divides the left hand, so it divides $b$.

Comment: To get $px + ay = 1$, that means gcd(p, a) = 1 so you could write a linear combination of 1 from p and a. However, how did you get gcd(p, a) = 1?

Comment: I assume $p\not |a$

Comment: However, although from your answer you can conclude that $p \, | \, b$, the goal of the problem is to prove for this case that $p^k \, | \, b$. How do you get from $p \, | \, b$ to $p^k \, | \, b$?

Comment: @ThomasLiu Or there is a better way, I edited.

Comment: If p does not divide a and p is prime, that means gcd(p, a) = 1. I still am confused as to how you got that $gcd(p^k, a) = 1$ to write that linear combination.

Comment: ERROR The argument assumes (without justification) that $p\nmid a\Rightarrow (p^k,a) = 1.\,$ But common ways of justifying that do use FTA (or equivalent). So we can't judge if this is a correct proof avoiding FTA till you supply such justification.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition** If $c | (ab)$ and $(c, a) = 1,$ then $c | b.$

**Lemma** Given $p$ a prime, if $c | p^k,$ then $c = p^i,\,0\le i\le k$

---

- If $(p^k, a) = 1,$ then $p^k | b.$
- If $(p^k, a) = p^k,$ then $p^k | a.$
- If $(p^k, a) = p^i,\,0 < i < k.$
  Suppose that $a = p^ic,\,(p^{k - i}, c) = 1,$ then, $p^k | ab\Leftrightarrow p^{k - i} | cb\Rightarrow p^{k - i} | b.$ Then $(a, b)\neq 1.$ Contradiction as $a$ and $b$ are coprime by assumption.

---

**Lemma proof**

Suppose that $c = p^ib,\, (b, p) = 1,$ as the only divisors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$ itself, then $c | p^k\Leftrightarrow b | p^{k - i}.$ Using the above **Proposition**, by induction, this eventually leads to $b | p.$ Then, $b =  1.$

---

**Proposition proof**
As $(c, a) = 1,$ then $1$ is a linear combination of $c$ and $a,$ i.e. $1 = mc + na\Rightarrow b = mbc + n(ab).$ As $ab = ck,$ then $b = mbc + nck = c(mb + nk),$ so $c | b.$

Answer (score 0):

A simple induction shows this is *equivalent* to EL = [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242) (i.e. case $k\! =\! 1).\,$ Indeed, case $\,k\!=\!0\,$ is trivial &  $\,k\!=\!1\,$ is EL, so assume $k> 1$. By EL: $\,p\mid p^k\mid ab\Rightarrow p\mid a\,$ or $\,b.\,$ Wlog $\,p\mid b.\,$ Cancel $p\Rightarrow p^{k-1}\mid \color{#c00}a(\color{#0a0}{b/p}).\,$ By induction $\,p^{k-1}\mid \color{#c00}a\,$ or $\,\color{#0a0}{b/p}$, but $\, p\mid p^{k-1}\mid\color{#c00} a\Rightarrow p\mid a,b\,$ contra $(a,b)\!=\!1.\,$ So it must be that $\,p^{k-1}\mid \color{#0a0}{b/p}\:\!\underset{\times\ p}\Longrightarrow p^k\mid b.\ $ QED

Due to this equivalence your question boils down to proving EL (case $k\!=\!1\,$) without FTA. But this is the most common way to prove EL and you can find most of these well-known proofs in prior answers here. The most common is to employ Bezout's GCD identity - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1260473/242). Alternatively we can give direct inductive proofs that essentially unwind the Euclidean descent inline, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217421/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216353/242), which are employed in direct proofs of FTA (by Zermelo and others).

Or we can use $(p,a) = 1\Rightarrow (p^k,a)=1$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696473/242), so $\,p^k\mid ab\Rightarrow p^k\mid b\,$ by general EL [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20093/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242).

**Remark** $ $ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611202/242) for *much* more on the *logical* relationships between FTA and EL and closely related factorization properties.

Comment: @Downvoter Above is correct (and key to the matter). If something is not clear then please ask questions before downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a=a_1^{k_1}×a_2^{k_2}×a_3^{k_3}×\dots a_m^{k_m}$(prime factorization of $a$) and $b=b_1^{p_1}×b_2^{p_2}×b_3^{p_3}×\dots b_n^{p_n}$(prime factorization of $b$) where $a_1,a_2,\dots a_m, b_1,b_2,\dots b_n$ are all distinct primes as $a$ and $b$ have no common factors.

If $p^k\,| \,ab$, then $p^k\,| \,(a_1^{k_1}×a_2^{k_2}×a_3^{k_3}×\dots a_m^{k_m}×b_1^{p_1}×b_2^{p_2}×b_3^{p_3}×\dots b_n^{p_n})$.

$p^k$ has no prime factor other than $p$. So $p^k$ must divide either $a_1^{k_1}$ or $a_2^{k_2}$ or $\dots $ or $a_m^{k_m}$ or $b_1^{p_1}$ or $b_2^{p_2}$ or $\dots$ or $b_n^{p_n}$.

If $p^k$ divides $a_x^{k_x}$, then $p^k\,| \,a$.

If $p^k$ divides $b_x^{p_x}$, then $p^k\,| \,b$

I have tried going as basic as I can. I hope now its clear to you.

Comment: This uses FTA (existence & uniqueness of prime factorizations) - which OP seeks to avoid, so this does not answer the question.