# Summation and sequence series question

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Sum of fifty positive nos.  is 1.

Find maximum value of sum of their inverse.

I have no idea how to solve this question... do not mark it as off topic or anything...

Maybe we should use AM>=GM?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840720/qm-am-gm-hm-proof-help

Comment: yaa what after that?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee  it asks for maximum value... the link helps to give minimum value maybe... 2500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum is infinity. Take one of the number to approach $0$ and all the others sum to approach $1$.

Comment: minimum value 2500?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to obtain the minimum?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{50}$ positive numbers such that their sum is $1$.

We can prove that the sum $\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x_{50}}$ is not bounded.

Let $M>1$, then by putting $x_1=\frac{1}{2M}$ and $x_2=x_3=\dots =x_{50}=\frac{1}{49}\left(1-\frac{1}{2M}\right)$ we get
$$\frac{1}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{x_{50}}=2M+\underbrace{\frac{98}{2M-1}+\frac{98}{2M-1}+\ldots+\frac{98}{2M-1}}_{49\text{ times}}>M$$

Answer (score -1):

Assume that the numbers are equal. Therefore the number must be $1/50$
When you say inverse if you mean reciprocal then the maximum value of the reciprocal becomes $50*50=2500$
Science I assumed the numbers are equal their sums are the maximum

Comment: shouldnt minimum be 2500?

Comment: Sorry, what was I thinking, we can set every 49 numbers to zero by letting the denominator to aproach to infinity and the last number to approach to one. The reciprocal being $\infinity$. 2500 being the minimum value because 50 being the maximum denominator for every function.... Sorry,

Comment: no problem.... :)