# Prove GM-AM inequality using induction

Tags: induction

Show that $G_{2^n}\le A_{2^n}$ by using induction on n.

I've proven the base case in the previous exercise:

Let $G_2=\sqrt{a_1a_2}$ and $A_2=\frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2)$ and     $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\sqrt{a_1a_2}\le \frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2)$$
$$2\sqrt{a_1a_2}\le (a_1+a_2)$$
$$4a_1a_2\le a_1^2+2a_1a_2+a_2^2$$
$$0\le a_1^2-2a_1a_2+a_2^2$$
$$0\le (a_1-a_2)^2$$

which is true for all real numbers.

Where I'm having the issue is adding the $(k+1)$ to the inequality.

For k:
$G_{2^k} = (a_1a_2\cdots a_{2^{k}})^{\frac{1}{2^{k}}}$

For $2^{k+1}$:

$G_{2^{k+1}} = ((a_1a_2\cdots a_{2^{k}})^{\frac{1}{2^k}})^{\frac{k}{k+1}}\cdot a_{2^{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}$

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75669/using-strong-induction-to-get-the-am-gm-inequality-for-2n-numbers, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/geometric-mean-never-exceeds-arithmetic-mean/27334#27334 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97350/how-does-backwards-induction-work-to-prove-a-property-for-all-naturals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the two term AM-GM to
$$
(a_1a_2\dots a_n)^{\frac1n}\le\tfrac1n(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)
$$
and
$$
(a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\dots a_{2n})^{\frac1n}\le\tfrac1n(a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\dots+a_{2n})
$$

**Note:** you are only being asked to show this for groups of numbers whose size is a power of $2$.

Comment: And just like that it makes perfect sense. Thanks, robjohn.